# Turn main screen off when watching full screen video on TV

Tags: display, hdmi

I connect my Mac via an HDMI adapter to my TV to watch films.

Is there a way to turn off my Mac's screen while watching those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decrease brightness to the lowest level would be the best option for me.

There are many other solitons in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/how-do-i-turn-off-laptop-display-when-i-have-an-external-display).