# Turn off the macbook main display while working with monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

MBP 2015 13, 10.12.2

I want to use an external display via HDMI and turn off my Macbook Pro's display. How can I do it?

***Update***

There is another question: [How do I turn off laptop display when I have an external display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21729/how-do-i-turn-off-laptop-display-when-i-have-an-external-display]), but I don't think this one should be marked as duplicate.

Its 2017 now and the old question has answers from 2011-2014.

The other thing is - that the old question has also links to other answers and solutions. With this question we have answer with 2 variations of how to do it in one place.

Comment: Are you using the internal keyboard and mouse at the same time with the external display or an external keyboard and mouse with the external display? If the latter, just close the lid on the MacBook as an external display, keyboard and mouse will work with the MacBook in clamshell mode.

Comment: @user3439894 I would use the internal keyboard and mouse if it possible

Comment: @MikroDel Can't you just turn down the brightness all the way then?

Comment: @owlswipe please update your answer with this information. It will have than both variation - I will accept it. thanks :)

Comment: @MikroDel Done.

Comment: The update needs to be edited - remove the "this isn't a dupe - that's for [meta] discussion" just make exactly clear how the current situation is materially different from the linked question (keep the link though). If the only difference is old - we strongly prefer to close as dupe and get the correct answer in the old thread.

Comment: Simply set laptop's brightness to off

Comment: Some users report being able to use the SwitchResX utility to selectively turn off monitors. See this [blog post](https://kitze.io/posts/multiple-monitors-macos) and this AskDifferent [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/389201/41838).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Using an external keyboard and mouse/trackpad

You can use *Closed Clamshell Mode*. This is a feature built in to Macbooks that allows you to use them like desktop computers, with the lid closed and using a monitor as your only screen.

You'll need:

- An AC power adapter (like [this one](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD565LL/A/apple-60w-magsafe-2-power-adaptermacbook-pro-with-13-inch-retina-display?fnode=8b))
- An external keyboard and mouse or trackpad, either USB or wireless (like [this keyboard](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLA22LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english?fnode=56) and [this trackpad](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ2R2LL/A/magic-trackpad-2?fnode=56))
- An external display or projector (like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UFCVKI4))
- (Optional) A dock for your MBP (like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016EWLDTE))

To put your MBP into Closed Clamshell Mode:

- Connect your keyboard and mouse/trackpad to the computer
- Plug the computer into power
- Connect it via HDMI or Thunderbolt to the external monitor
- Close the lid
- OR place a weak magnet next to your trackpad (the sensor for closed lid detection is there & magnetic) for better cooling (I use an old iPad case)

Once in Closed Clamshell Mode, the Macbook's screen will turn off and it will still be outputting picture to the monitor. Read more [on Apple's support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834).

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

### Using the built-in keyboard and trackpad

You can dim your Macbook's screen all the way down (just press brightness down repeatedly) and then connect the Macbook to your monitor with HDMI. Your screen will be off but the keyboard and trackpad built into the Macbook will still be on and available. Optionally, you can download the free app [Amphetamine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12) to keep your Mac from sleeping.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, "turning down the internal monitor" is not a solution.  When you dim the screen, it does not go off, you just cant see what's on it. when a window opens on this screen for example, its invisible - you can't find it. You have to keep putting the brightness up, moving the window, the putting the brightness down.   We still need a way to use the keyboard and FPR and having the screen disabled. This is such a basic feature which is missing.  Also, frequently when you close the lid, it's not possible to get the machine to come back on with  USB keyboard and mouse.

Comment: @JohnLittle do any answers in the linked duplicate post fix the issue you speak of? I'm not really sure of a better way myself.

Comment: @JohnLittle is correct. Only the monitor backlight gets turned off, not the actual screen. Another solution would be preferable since keeping the screen opened helps keep the laptop cooler.

Comment: @JohnLittle But that's the only solution that actually works. The clamshell mode will stall my wifi speed to a few mbps (while it's 150 mbps when lid is open).

Comment: @JohnLittle if you have one external display, you can set display to "mirror", so then when you dim the laptop screen - you don't really lose much.

Comment: @TamikSoziev thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I have 2 x 32" external monitors, so mirroring is not an option in this case.

Comment: @JohnLittle, "you can't find it" - for this ( if you don't have a touch-bar) you can drag the brightness menu to the external display.  If you have a touch bar; you can easily bring the brightness to 0 with it.  Thanks! :)

Comment: I've been going with a really silly solution that works for me. Turn on mirroring, which seems to use the larger monitor's resolution, and dim the Macbook's screen entirely.

Comment: I think one issue now is with newer Intel-based MBPros is the thermal disadvantage of keeping the lid closed while working with external M&K + Monitor. For VM and other slightly CPU heavy tasks, the laptop runs 20c hotter with much more fan variance when closed versus open. So there is a valid use case to keep the lid open but not have the built in display active.  Dimming the display doesn't disable it which also adjusts my monitor based off it's brightness sensor so there are a lot of settings to account for when working with external monitors and having the lid open.

Comment: Mirroring the screen (any screen if you have more than one) works. Then you can dim the built in screen.

Comment: I set a black wallpaper on the laptop screen when I need to work with the lid open. It’s not ideal, but it’s a practical workaround to the issues @JohnLittle and @ Chase mentioned. If a window pops up, I’ll see it – but it's not distracting. The laptop also doesn’t heat up too much during CPU-intensive work.

Comment: I am using DisplayLink drivers for a multi-monitor setup, which can mirror to one monitor, while another monitor is extended display using the laptop keyboard and trackpad.