# Turn off the built-in monitor on MBP El Capitan with clamshell open

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I usually plug my MBP 15" late 2011 (El Capitan 10.11.2) with an external monitor, and I only use that. Also I need to use the trackpad.

So I need to **turn off the built-in monitor with the clamshell open**. Possibly using a **terminal command**. How can do it?

I already tried this solution (for Yosemite) but doesn't work on El capitan: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/154600/90762

And I already tried [DisableMonitor](https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor) app but it reduces the brightness of the monitor to 0 and it remains on! So probably it consumes more. Is there a way to completely turn off?

Comment: I changed title and description to better focus my problem, that is turn off monitor with clamshell open and possibly using a terminal command on El Capitan.

Comment: What about set brightness to zero? Or does that also affect the external display?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that all terminal and app based solutions won't work in El Capitan because of [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). Although [it can be disabled](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208478/126929), [this might be the easiest solution](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15734/126929).

Comment: @Joonas: is it reccomendable to disable it or it's like an hack? Anyway, if I use the notable DisableMonitor app (as everyone seem to use with great satisfaction) it simply decreases the luminosity to 0 but is it the same as disable the monitor, in terms of consumption?

Comment: @FredK, to be honest, I couldn't tell you if or how any of those solutions worked on prior versions, since I haven't tried any of them. [This makes me think that DisableMonitor had to settle for brightess reduction in El Capitan (for now?)](https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor/issues/45). The terminal solutions seem pretty legit too, [this one for example](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6601019?tstart=0). I'd guess they don't work because of SIP.

Comment: I don't know too much beyond the basics of SIP, so maybe I'm the wrong person to say anything about it, but El Capitan is currently the only osx version with SIP. It's not really a hack to disable it, but you are throwing a way a level of security with it (level of security that did not exist in any prior os x version). SIP can be re-enabled. In some cases you can disable it, do your changes and enable it again. Then you'd have to do the same thing to enable the screen, assuming that disabling the screen is permanent and it doesn't get turned back on after a reboot.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just mirror the display of the MacBook screen to the external one and then turn off the brightness of the Macbook screen (so it turns fully black).
Then you can keep the lid open of your MacBook AND use the TrackPad.

System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement > Select "Mirror Displays".

Comment: Note that this only turns off the backlight, but the display is still on.

Answer (score 1):

Given how none of the old methods seemed to work in El Capitan, the magnet method sounded pretty interesting to me, so I decided to try it.

I got the smallest and weakest hobby/craft magnet I had, and ran it through the top left corner of the Macbook Air, as some of those other answers said that's the location. I suspect the location may differ between Macbook models.

In my `MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)`, the location seemed to be on the left side, slightly above the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

I used [Pritt multi tack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yssZz.jpg) to keep the magnet in place, but you could use double sided tape, for example. If I wanted to be really careful with the magnet, I could've put a spacer between the Macbook surface and the magnet about the height of the magnet itself, and it still would've worked.

**There's one kinda big downside to this.**

- If you stop using the Macbook touchpad or keyboard for something like 3 seconds, they stop working. You then need to remove the magnet to re-enable them. This is kind of a deal-breaker, if you don't want to use external mouse and keyboard.

If you are ok with using an external keyboard and mouse, this seems like the best method to me.

[image]

Comment: The magnet method is an old classic! I always avoid it because I'm afraid to put any magnetic object close to any electronic device. I knew that magnet could create issues to electronic devices (such as hard disk). Is it right?

Comment: @FredK When you think about it, macbook's have plenty of magnets already. This might depend on the model, but there's: 2 magnets on top of the screen, on both sides of the camera. Those keep the lid firmly closed. There's the charging port magnet and then here's the magnet that closes the screen. What they use there is a [reed switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) (to my knowledge). They are already using a magnet to activate it so I personally don't feel too much anxiety sticking a magnet there myself. As long as the magnet is small and not very strong, my mind is at ease.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't run a horseshoe magnet all around the laptop :) [Here's a picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xYbxD.jpg) where I placed an average metal wire on the lid. This is the magnet that closes the screen, when you close the lid. You can use that point to determine how strong of a magnet you should use in its place (not very stong at all). 
If using a magnet to do this still seems scary, [reading this should ease your mind](http://www.howtogeek.com/124713/are-modern-computers-still-vulnerable-to-damage-via-magnets/).

Answer (score 0):

Close the lid of your MacBook.

Comment: It goes to standby then turn off also the external monitor

Comment: Does it wake back up if you press a key on your keyboard?

Comment: This is a very bad suggestion, due to how hot the Macbook gets when the display is closed, blocking the vents just north of the keyboard.

Comment: I read somewhere (I can't find the link) that MBP dissipate on the bottom, so there are no problems to keep the lid close. I could be right, but I'm with @Martin

Answer (score -1):

SwitchResX works for me: you can easily disable displays in its GUI.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We are looking for more than a single line answer.  It's helpful if you provide links and/or references to solutions you have found and *why* you think your answer is right.